# How To Fix Rotation -- Global vs Local

Tags: animation

I just found out about this situation. So my scene involves different propellers facing on different directions.

Now the ones that are globally aligned, i don't have a problem rotating it to the Y axis because it's position is relative to global orientation. I get into trouble with propellers facing different direction. I cannot rotate them properly anymore.

Here is an example of my scene:
https://youtu.be/Pd1ffT_APTo

So my qeustion is can you rotate object basing on there LOCAL POSITIONING? not GLOBAL?

[image]

Comment: Make sure, that the axis (which the Propellers rotate on) is the ***first*** axis of the Rotation Order. If not, set it and redo your Animation keyframes.

Comment: But concerning your actual question: No, you can parent the object to other object though, thus creating a "local" space.

Comment: @Leander you just solved my problem :) THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Check out the solution you proposed :)

https://youtu.be/2WB8hWYqfsI